# How are these 2 instance attributes are connected to each other?

Tags: python, class, python-class

```
class Library :
    
    def __init__(self,booklist) :
        self.permabooklist = booklist
        self.books = booklist

sonipatlibrary = Library(["C++","Django","Flask","Oops"])

print(sonipatlibrary.permabooklist)
print(sonipatlibrary.books)
sonipatlibrary.books.remove("Django")
print(sonipatlibrary.permabooklist)
print(sonipatlibrary.books)
```

my question is why is "Django" being removed from sonipatlibrary.permabooklist

**what is the connection between these 2 independent instance attributes?**

Comment: they both have reference to the exact same list, so when you change self.books, your changing actually the list referenced by self.books. self.permabooklist is pointing to the same reference so it will also change.

Comment: how can i create a copy instead of referencing ?

Comment: You can give books a copy like this: `self.books = booklist[:]`